# Core Data: Which record loads by default in core data if you do not specify which one?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a static table for settings where I want to pull some stuff from an entity in Core Data. The use case does not lend itself to a table of records as you usually see.  Rather each row of the static table is really a field related to the user--as in a user profile. I have a feeling that in testing I may have created more than one record in the entity.  I know there are programs that let you see the SQL lite database underneath, but my question assumes you do not have this tool and are relying just on Xcode.

My question is when you have more than one record in a Core Data entity/table, and you try to load data from the managed object context into a VC, one field into one element, what record is shown by default?

Related to this, if you don't know how many managed object or rows are in the database, is there anyway to specify which record you want since there are no auto ids as you would use in a traditional database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The record that gets loaded from the fetch first.  Depending on your sort that might be consistent or it might be random.